# WebDriver / stuck when open upload file window

Tags: firefox, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I use my WebDriver, with FireFox.

I have an elemnt: //input[@class="uploadFiles"], when I click on it by:
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class="uploadFiles"]")), a windows of upload a file (Windows OS's  window) is opened, but the test doesn't continue to the next line, and get stuck.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Webdriver doesnt interact with os level dialogs and that's the reason it doesnt continue to the next line.  Here's something to help you : http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q:_Does_WebDriver_support_file_uploads?

Answer (score 2):

No you cant do it with WebDriver as niharika_neo answer but you can do next:

```
string filepath = "my local path";
_driver.FindElement(By.Id("attachments")).SendKeys(filepath);
_driver.FindElement(By.Id("attachments")).SendKeys(Keys.Return);
```

Comment: Do yo mean that I will do: _driver.FindElement(By.xpath(" //input[@class="uploadFiles")]).SendKeys(filepath);
_driver.FindElement(By.xpath(" //input[@class="uploadFiles")]).SendKeys(Keys.Return);

Because when I do it, the windows doesn't open at all

Comment: @Adam Sh You don't need to open window for upload you need to pass full file name and then upload your file.

Comment: But my line is not a windows line! it is a website line, and when I enter on it, it open a windows line

Comment: @Adam Sh So you test should check for opened window and close it is i understand you?

Comment: No, my test should do the next: 1) click on the upload line (this doesn't, as I understood, a windows line, and the xpath of this line is: //input[@class="uploadFiles")]). 2) Then it should choose a document - this is a windows OS window. 3) then it should submit the file

Answer (score 1):

You can't interact with OS level Windows directly. You can go through the path given by niharika_neo or else you can use Auto IT tool for handling the OS level windows. The best option is to use Auto IT tool.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem with FF, then I found that it was specific to the FF version I am using. I installed and ran the tests on FF 11, and I was able to successfully runt he tests. Try changing the version of FF that you are using.